# "Error Loading operating system" on QEMU

Tags: windows, windows-xp, virtual-machine, vmware, qemu

The Windows 2000 Professional virtual machine is essentially installed on VMWare Workstation Pro, when I convert the VMDK file to QCOW2 or run the VMDK file directly using Virt-Manager, it shows "Error loading Operating System", I don't know why that happens, I tried my best to make the settings in QEMU match VMWare's settings.

Comment: Why not just use [VMWare Workstation Player](https://www.vmware.com/uk/products/workstation-player.html)? It looks like it should be fine for Windows 2000 guests and the FAQ says "VMware Workstation Player is free for personal, non-commercial use"

Comment: OP indicates they’re using _virt-manager_ which basically implies Linux. Using VMware products on Linux is not a great experience. That being said, it’s hard to guess what’s going on here. How does the error message look like? Is it QEMU (or SeaBIOS) generating the message? Or NTLDR?

Comment: It shows SeaBIOS

Comment: To be exact, it shows SeaBIOS, then booting into Hard Drive and then the error shows "Error Loading the operating system"

Comment: @DanielB I think you will also need to know that the hard drive type is SCSI

Comment: @DanielB Update: I have converted the hard drive to IDE but still has the same problem, and I didn't found virtio drivers for windows 2000.